# How to generate a visual sitemap of an existing site?

Tags: xml, sitemap

I have a site with many pages many of which depend on the user to login before the access. I have to generate a site map of the website for some tracking and progress recording purpose. It is very hard for me to  manually create the sitemap as it is a huge website. Can i find a free visual site map builder tht will automatically generate the sitemap for me? i have the sitemap in my website defined as an xml file (web.sitemap) so if there is something to convert xml to a visual format that would also do for me.

Answer (score 1):

I assume there is no simple solution tool for your setup. One kind of sitemap(s) is for the [searchengines](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184) to better spider your (huge) website. They need the subset of content that is accessible without authentication.

The other kind of (visual) sitemap is part of a better information architecture to help users navigate. Again you'll have to decide whether pages that need authentication are always visible in your sitemap or are listed in the map only after login. If your site is huge you'll probably have to split the map to multiple maps based on per-rubric-navigation elements or loading parts via AJAX mechanisms.

Maybe you provide more details about your setup / framework.

Comment: actually i just need it for documentation purposes and i want the pages to appear in the site map all the time. I will need to provide this document to the client to track the progress tht these pages are done and these are not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are many dot.net controls (visual) that can read the web.sitemap file. But that part is outside my expertise.

However, you don't say what you mean by visual sitemap-

Do you mean you need to be able to visually inspect all pages?
Create HTML sitemap?
Create "eyecandy" HTML sitemap that looks "graphical"?
or? :)

You write you just need a sitemap builder for job documentation purposes? If it's just for a one-off (or 30 days), you could expand to try tools like A1 Sitemap Generator that have a trial period.